# Splitting a line with two or single string in two variables bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to separate the contents of the line in bash. My code is something like this.

```
 while read line; do
    var1=${line% *}
    var2=${line#* }
    echo -e "var1[$var1] var2[$var2]"
 done < "shares.lst"
```

And my `shares.lst` looks like this:

```
defaults data
sample here
okay
```

The output is this:

```
var1[defaults] var2[data]
var1[sample] var2[here]
var1[okay] var2[okay]
```

The problem occurs when the line is just one. What approach should I do so that I could check if the variable I can take is only one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` can split for you:

```
while read var1 var2; do
   echo -e "var1[$var1] var2[$var2]"
done < "shares.lst"
```

will output

```
var1[defaults] var2[data]
var1[sample] var2[here]
var1[okay] var2[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compare var1 against var2 for equality and echo your result if they are not equal. like,

```
if ["$var1" != "$var2"]; then
    echo -e "var1[$var1] var2[$var2]"
```